# Cross-Region access to CodeCommit repository from CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am building a CodePipeline using CloudFormation. The pipeline is deployed to the `eu-west-1` region however it must get the source code from the CodeCommit repository that is located in the `us-east-1` region.

The pipeline definition looks like this:

```
CodePipeline:
  Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref PipelineName
    RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn
    Stages:
      - Name: Source
        Actions:
          - Name: Source
            ActionTypeId:
              Category: Source
              Owner: AWS
              Provider: CodeCommit
              Version: 1
            OutputArtifacts:
              - Name: SourceCodeOutputArtifact
            Configuration:
              RepositoryName: !Ref MyRepository
              BranchName: !Ref DeploymentBranch
            RunOrder: 1
            Region: us-east-1
```

The attached role and policy looks like this:

```
CodePipelineServiceRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
          Principal:
            Service:
              - codepipeline.amazonaws.com

CodePipelineServicePolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
  Properties:
    PolicyName: CodePipelineServicePolicy
    Roles:
      - !Ref CodePipelineServiceRole
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
......
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - codecommit:BatchGet*
            - codecommit:BatchDescribe*
            - codecommit:Get*
            - codecommit:Describe*
            - codecommit:List*
            - codecommit:GitPull
          Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:MyRepository*"
```

Alas, the code pipeline still don't have access to my repository in the `us-east-1`, or it is looking for it in the incorrect region, and as a result I'm getting the following error

```
The service role or action role doesn’t have the permissions required to access the AWS CodeCommit repository named MyRepository. Update the IAM role permissions, and then try again. Error: User: arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/MyPipeline-CodePipelineServiceRole-N996SC3JYINW/1564844186052 is not authorized to perform: codecommit:GetBranch on resource: arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:111111111111:MyRepository
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I know that I can replicate the repo to another region but I am wondering is there any way to do what I want to do without replicating the repo to another region?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the codecommit to the other region. You can do it by using a CI Job, a scheduled container in ECS or Fargate.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I know about cross-region replication but was trying to avoid it. I will update my question to clarify that. Is there any way to accomplish that without replicating the repo?

Comment: Have you tried cross-region actions: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-cross-region-actions/

Comment: Unfortunately, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html the source action is (still) not supported as cross-region action...